# Move Azure API Management Operation to New API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to move an *operation* defined in Azure APIM to a different API than it was originally defined in?  I'd like to reorganize some operations into new APIs w/o having to manually recreate the operation in the desired location.  (Note that the APIs have not been published to production as of yet, so this won't be a breaking change.)  I don't see any way to accomplish this via the APIM UI and haven't had much luck at finding a programmatic way to do this.

For example using the image below, how would I move the **POST Add a Customer Address** operation from the **Customer Management API** to the **Prospect Customer API**?

[image]

Comment: At present,from the Azure portal this can't be achieved. But yes as you have rightly mention you can manually recreate the operation at desired location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not a perfect solution, the [Azure RM API Management PowerShell library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/?view=azurermps-6.13.0#api_management) helped me to build a PowerShell script that gets me most of what I wanted, but still requires a little manual labor.

In PowerShell, I created an `array` of operation IDs that I want to move, then used a combination of the following functions in a `for-each` loop to 'move' the `operations` to the desired API:

- [Get-AzureRmApiManagementOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/get-azurermapimanagementoperation?view=azurermps-6.13.0) - Used to read the existing operation.
- [New-AzureRmApiManagementOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/new-azurermapimanagementauthorizationserver?view=azurermps-6.13.0) - Used to create a new operation based on the existing one created by mapping the results of the Get function to this New function. *Note that there is a 1000 character limit on the Description field.*
- [Remove-AzureRmApiManagementOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/remove-azurermapimanagementoperation?view=azurermps-6.13.0) - Used to remove the operation from the old API location.  *I don't recommend using this unless you are darn sure the previous steps worked exactly as you want.*  Because I ran into an issue where the operation description field can only be 1000 characters or less, I'm glad I didn't delete the operation from the old location because I had to manually copy/paste the description into the new location.

While the above functions will help in copying the `operations`, the `policies` within each `operation` won't be copied.  Therefore, the following functions can be used to ensure the `policies` are copied as well:

- [Get-AzureRmApiManagementPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/get-azurermapimanagementpolicy?view=azurermps-6.13.0) - Used to get the XML policy from an operation as a string.
- [Set-AzureRmApiManagementPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/set-azurermapimanagementpolicy?view=azurermps-6.13.0) - Use the policy string obtained from the previous function call to set the policy string on the newly created operation.